# How to configure the time it takes for a kafka to strat streaming?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I have the following setup:

- Dockerized environments (in docker-compose.yml):

  - zookeeper image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:3'
  - kafka image: kafka:dev
  - pipeline (own image)
- 1 kafka brokers and a 1 zookeeper ensamble

When I'm starting my docker-compose following configuration will be applied (please see attached code).

After zookeeper and Kafka is up and running (and listen to each other) pipeline should start streaming the data.

For some unknown reason, streaming will start after 10 minutes delay. This problem occurs each time when and reproduced only in docker.

[sample of the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI8qd.png)

Does anyone know what config parameters in Kafka and/or zookeeper influence the time taken for start streaming? Or any way to debug what's exactly going on with Kafka and zookeeper during these ten minutes?

I apologize in advance if my question is too general. I'm a beginner with Kafka.

I have tried to change the different time out parameters but it doesn't help to fix this problem. 
Sample of the configs parameters which I have changed:

- `zookeeper tickTime = 2000`
- `kafka zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 6000`
  (basically the default config)

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:3'
    ports:
      - '2182:2182'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes

  kafka:
    image: kafka:dev
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    links: 
     - zookeeper
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092

  pipeline:
    image: project-pipeline:dev
    links: 
      - "kafka"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

After Kafka and zookeeper containers up and running pipeline container should start streaming to Kafka without any delays.

Comment: what is the pipeline container doing during that time? This image is yours, we don't know what it does, so you need to provide/check its logs.

Comment: Yes, of course. I will be glad to tell in details what exactly pipeline container is doing: basically inside the container python file is executing, which stream CSV file into the Kafka on a continuous basis (each portion of data every 5 seconds).

Comment: Please let me know which logs exactly might help to bring the clarity into this issue. I will prepare this log.

Comment: Logs from the Python Kafka client would be useful